# The User.IsInRole working for Admin but false for other users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, isinrole

In my _Layout.chtml, I want to show menu on the navbar based on the user role. To make it short, I have "Admin" and "User" role. Here is my code in the _Layout.html

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>

                @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Manage Users</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("User", "Index", "User")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
        }
        else if (User.IsInRole("User"))
                    {
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">User</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("User2", "Index2", "User2")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
        }
                else
                {
                }

            </ul>
        </div>
```

The problem is, When I login a user with "Admin" role, I can see the menu. But when I login using "User", nothing. As if the (User.IsInRole("User")) is false. User authenticated successfully (There's no "Wrong password" warning). What can be the cause of this?

UPDATE: Here's what I tried so far.   1. Change the user (with "User" role) role to "Admin", user can see the menu.   2. Change the arrangement of the code (If "User" ..... Else "Admin"), still "User") user cannot see the menu.

When I login with "Admin" user, it will redirect to the homepage and menu will appear. 
When I login using "User" user, it will stay on the login page, username textbox intact, 
password textbox blank, and no warning whatsoever

When I login with "Admin" user, "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" is true.
With "User", its False.

In all controller, I've added this...
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,User")]

...All to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure that User has an "User" role?

Comment: Completely sure. Here's what I tried so far.
1. Change the user role to "Admin", user can see the menu.
2. Change the arrangement  of the code (If "User" ..... Else "Admin"), still user cannot see the menu.

Comment: When I login with "Admin" user, it will redirect to the homepage and menu will appear. When I login using "User" user, it will stay on the login page, username textbox intact, password textbox blank, and no warning whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

When user is logged in successfully,

First check what are the available roles for the **Authenticated** user... According to this we can check in different angles

```
  @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                 string[] r = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
                 string s = string.Join(",", r.ToList());
                <h1>@s</h1>
}
```

Comment: I got these: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The login method in AccountController was changed and I forgot about it.

```
if ((UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin")) || (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "User")))
{
await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```